# SPARQL for Pizza Ontology CQ

Tags: sparql, ontology

so I used [pizza ontology](http://protege.stanford.edu/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl), and tried to do some competence questions below using SPARQL

1. what kind of pizza are there?
2. is topping necessary for pizza?

here's what I've come to understand so far:

I try to list pizza's subclasses by this query

```
SELECT ?p WHERE { ?p rdfs:subClassOf pizza:Pizza }
```

it only display NamedPizza, I understand why, because NamedPizza is the only class that has direct subclass relationship, meanwhile other class like CheeseyPizza is owlEquivalentClass with certain attributes, and American is subclass of NamedPizza. So, if I want to list all the kind of pizza in this ontology, including CheeseyPizza and American, what query will it be?

related to 2nd question, since Pizza definition is only mention that it has PizzaBase, and PizzaTopping only mentioned in specific Pizza subclass/equivalentClass (for example: CheeseyPizza has CheeseTopping), how to test that a Pizza must have PizzaTopping or not?

Comment: If the rdfs:subClassTriples are not present directly in the data, then you'll need a reasoner, or a much more complex SPARQL query that can look for other kinds of relationships as well.

Comment: You can use predicate rdfs:subClassOf* to get sub-subclasses you explicitly asserted, etc., but as @JoshuaTaylor mentioned, you'll need a reasoner to capture the inferred relationships.

Comment: I guess I have to learn about using reasoner first